# How to process a parameter c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have one program which processes different file types. It can be an orders file, or ship confirms, or Invoices, etc.

I have setup code files to handle each sort of file types.

In my main program.cs all I am doing is to check which file type and to then run the correct code files. This here is hard coded to run type 2. We will have an SQL agent job that will run this program exe and will pass which file type as 1,2,3 etc.

my question is, how to code my program, to be receiving such a parameter, and then pass into below code that parameter.

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProgramType"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                Order.RunOrder();
            }
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProgramType"].ToString() == "2")
            {
                Shipment.RunShipment();
```

Comment: In your program's `Main` method, you get a `string[] args` that will contain the command line arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We will have an SQL agent job that will run this program exe and will pass which file type as 1,2,3 etc.

If your application will be receiving arguments from the caller, then reading these variables from the configuration file is a bad idea.

If your process is a console application, why not use the already provided `Main` arguments?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    // Read program type, default is "1"
    string type = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : "1";

    switch(type)
    {
        case "1": { Order.RunOrder(); break; }
        case "2": { Shiptment.RunShipment(); break; }
        // ...
    }
}
```

The SQL agent will have to pass in this argument:

```
> yourProgram.exe 1
> yourProgram.exe 2

// Same as yourProgram.exe 1
> yourProgram.exe
```